# some issue with **keywords_arguments in python

Tags: python, function, arguments, maya

I have some issue trying to define keywords_aguments.
I'm trying to define a function that returns all the objects with *_control in the scene, when nothing is specified, but i'd like to choose which ones about 'left' or 'right' it has to return.
Below you can find my function. I don't understand where the error is.

```
from maya import cmds

def correct_value(selection=None, **keywords_arguments):
     if selection is None: 
        selection = cmds.ls ('*_control')    

     if not isinstance(selection, list):
        selection = [selection]

     for each in keywords_arguments:
         keywords_list = []
         if each.startswith('right','left'):
             selection.append(each)



    return selection

correct_value()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `keywords_list = []`?

Answer (score 3):

Keyword arguments are dictionaries. You can print them or could have verified the type with the `type()` function. This allows you to try use of dictionary in isolated context on your own and finding out how to solve your problem yourself.

Now, when you have a dictionary `x = {1:2}`, iterating over it with for will give you just one, i.e. it will only iterate over the keys(!), not the according values. For that, use `for key, value in dictionary.items()` and then use the value `if key in ('right', 'left')`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have would add 'right' or 'left' on to the end of the list.

I think you want something like this:

```
def find_controls(*selection, **kwargs): # with *args you can pass one item, several items, or a list
    selection = selection or cmds.ls("*_control") or [] # supplied objects, or the ls command, or an empty list

    if not kwargs:
        return list(selection) # no flags? reutrn the whole list

    lefty = lambda ctrl: ctrl.lower().startswith("left")  # this will filter for items with left
    righty = lambda ctrl: ctrl.lower().startswith("right")  # this will filter for items with left

    filters = [] 
    if kwargs.get('left'):  # safe way to ask 'is this key here and does it have a true value?'
       filters.append(lefty)

    if kwargs.get('right'):
       filters.append(righty)

    result = []
    for each_filter in filters:
        result += filter (each_filter, selection)

    return result


find_controls (left=True, right=True)
# Result: [u'left_control', u'right_control'] # 

find_controls (left=True, right =False) # or just left=True
# Result: [u'left_control'] # 

find_controls()
# Result: [u'left_control', u'middle_control',  u'right_control'] #
```

The trick here is to use the [lambdas](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) (which are basically just  functions in a shorter format) and the built in filter function (which applies a function to everything in a list and returns things where the function true a non-zero, non-false answer. It's easy to see how you could extend it just by adding more keywords and corresponding lambdas